# Perl Display files in DIR, Link and display in browser

Tags: perl

I have been searching the web and trying different variations of code so that the end user via a web interface can see all of the server backup logs and select anyone of them to read the log in a browser. I am working on a test system which is RHEL 6. There is the dir "/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/" where the backup logs are stored and it has files in it. I have even chmod 755 all of the dirs. and files (Just for testing)When I call the script from a browser I get the files I want displayed as hyperlinks. There was an issue where I would click on the link but perl was looking in the cgi-bin DIR so I forced it to look in "/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/"

```
    $list->a({-href=>"/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/$file"}),
```

which is cleaner by doing:

```
    $list->a({-href=>$fileDir.$file}),
```

where this used to be like this

```
    $list->a({-href=>$file}),
```

but as I stated would look in cgi-bin and not the log DIR.

So now the hyperlink is referencing the correct DIR and file but when click I still get file not found even though the file is there. Any help would be great! Out of ideas :(

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use CGI;
    use warnings;

    my $list = new CGI;
    my $fileDir = '/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/';
    my @files;

    print $fileDir;


    opendir DIR, "$fileDir";
    @files = grep(/\.log$/,readdir(DIR)); 


    closedir DIR;

    print $list->header("text/html"),
    $list->start_html("Files in $fileDir"),
    $list->p("These are the files in $fileDir");

    foreach my $file (@files) {
    print $list->p(
    $list->a({-href=>$fileDir.$file}),
    $file)

    }

    print $list->end_html;
```

Comment: `CGI` is deprecated, but not _that_ big a disaster. The alternatives are less than user friendly for a 'quicky' I find.

Comment: Unless you configure it otherwise, your webserver treats `/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/` as a path *relative to the webserver's document root.* If the document root is `/var/www/html` (the default for Apache on *nix, for example), the webserver will look for a file in `/var/www/html/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/`.

Comment: @Sobrique You misunderstood my question. Why is CGI needed for **this** specific situation?

Comment: @Sinan Ünür. This is for intranet not internet. 

!ThisSuitIsBlackNot THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

Good to Go! I added the following to the httpd.conf:

```
Alias /logs/ "/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/"

<Directory "/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and changed the code to reflect the alias

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;

my $list = new CGI;
my $fileDir = "/var/log/vista/stcr2tsvr/";
my $alias = "/logs/";
my @files;

print $fileDir;

opendir DIR, "$fileDir";

@files = grep(/\.log$/,readdir(DIR)); ## Example file to read 2015
+0210-dubr3psvr-backup.log

closedir DIR;

print $list->header("text/html"),
  $list->start_html("Files in $fileDir"),
  $list->p("These are the files in $fileDir");

foreach my $file (@files) {
print $list->p(
        $list->a({-href=>$alias.$file},
        $file)
        );
}

print $list->end_html;
```

Comment: There is a fundamental disconnect here: Why are you writing a CGI script to display the contents of a directory which you just made world browsable?! Also, keep in mind that `$` in a regex pattern also matches newlines.

Comment: This is Intranet not internet. It is for a sysadmon portal I am putting together for work. I have 20 other scripts which set up a clean web interface which I also have hooks for monitors and alerts. This will never go to the WWW.

Comment: You keep saying that as if it is relevant. Given that you have made the directory browsable by anyone able to connect to the web server, why are you writing a CGI script to list its contents?! But, I give up.

Comment: Admins need to view their backup logs via an easy web interface. That's why. Display the contents of the file and onclick view the file.(Might be ME not explaining properly). We are using CGI,perl and bash scripts. It is relevant that this can only be accessed by internal staff only. Our environment is closely monitored and we all have high security clearance so no one is hacking their own servers. You can not get to these servers from the outside as they are not networked that way(NO OUTSIDE CONTACT). If that does not answer your question then I give up...

Comment: You could also drop the CGI script and just use Apache's built-in [directory indexing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) directly. That would be simpler and less error-prone, but wouldn't allow you to filter out non `.log` files, for example. I think that's at least part of what Sinan Ünür is hinting at.

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. looking into that now.